# Hide CiviCRM navigation menu based on permission

Tags: menu

Any suggestions for a not-too-hacky way to hide the whole CiviCRM top navigation menu for users who don't have a particular permission? I could load some menu-hiding css or js conditional on permissions, maybe in Civi pageRun+buildForm hooks or Drupal preprocess_page hook - but that feels hacky.

CiviCRM 4.6, Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2):

There's a CiviCRM navigation hook that you could use in an extension *but*...

To me this is the wrong approach. Hiding the menu does not stop users from accessing those pages or using the API via JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I know that hiding a menu isn't a substitute for access control! However the requirement from the client is to hide the menu, in order to provide a simplified user interface for (un)certain users.

Answer (score 1):

Can this be done with Drupal user permissions (/admin/people/permissions) and roles? Our organization has a few staff users with varying levels of access; the "CiviCRM: access CiviCRM" permission is what gives users access to the top menu and the API, AFAIK. I've only given that permission to staffers who need full access, and i built custom menu blocks to give partial functionality to other staffers.

So, I have a Member Relations ACL role that has the "Access CiviCRM" permission, and then other ACL roles that don't have that but are enabled on some subcomponents. We're Drupal 7/Civi 4.7.4 right now and this approach has been working for us since 4.4.x. The permissions for Civi are pretty granular and there may be a way to accomplish what you need without writing module code.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post but I was looking to do something very similar and it took me a while to figure it out - so I'm sharing in case someone else finds it useful.

I did use the hook_civicrm_navigationMenu. But most of the documentation surrounded how to add something, not remove it. I used the unset function (just like it is used in the hook_civicrm_tabset). The only tricky part is adding the right references to hide the correct menu. For me, I wanted to hide the Mailings menu for 'uncertain' users as @davejenx describes them.

```
// identify id of Mailings menu in $params array    
$mailingsmenuID = CRM_Core_DAO::getFieldValue('CRM_Core_DAO_Navigation', 'Mailings', 'id', 'label');
// remove the menu
unset($params[$mailingsmenuID]);
```